# Mobile hotspot with wemos d1 mini

Tags: esp8266, wifi, networking

I recently got a wemos d1 mini and now am trying to connect it to my IPhone 13's hotspot, however it doesn't connect, I tried to run the wifiscan example - and it doesn't even detect it there.

I tried connecting it to my home router - and this worked hence I have no ideas on fixing it, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the iPhone hotspot is 5GHz only, which is why your ESP8266 can't see it. The ESP8266's WiFi radio is 2.4GHz only.

To enable 2.4GHz on the iPhone hotspot, turn on the "Maximize Compatibility" button under "Settings | Personal Hotspot". Then 2.4GHz devices should be able to connect to the phone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This completely fixed the issue.